# Change elements top position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with several  elements. 
They are absolutely positioned, each has css attribute "top".

I want to go through all of the elements and change their top position by 20px.
So it means I need to get current top position and add 20px to it.

The number of  elements is unknown as it can change at any time.

Thanks!

Comment: Try looking into the `.css` method ([https://api.jquery.com/css/](https://api.jquery.com/css/)). Also look into jQuery selectors, that will let you make the changes to all the elements at once ([https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gather the elements

```
var $elements = $("div");
```

Then iterate through each one of them and add the required

```
$elements.each(function () {
    $(this).css({top: "+=20px"});
})
```

Comment: This works, though only first three elements are being affected. 
Heres the code I am using:

`$j('article').each(function () {
     if ($j(this).css('top') != '0px') { $j(this).css('top', '-=20'); }
})`

There are 3 elements with top:0px; and other 10 elements with values greater than 0px, but only 3 out of 10 are being affected. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: The code you attached seems fine. Do you perhaps have more code that you could show to see the problem?

Comment: Well there's not much  to show. My each article element has css top values set to: 0, 0, 0, 250, 250 250, 520, 520, 520 and so on. But only those with top:250px are affected. They are positioned 3 in a row.

Comment: I just noticed that you're removing `-=20`, don't forget the `px` so that it is `-=20px`. If that doesn't help, try some debugging with the following code `$j('article').each(function () { console.log("Elem with top: " + $j(this).css('top')); if ($j(this).css('top') != '0px') { console.log("Remove 20px"); $j(this).css('top', '-=20'); } });`. Open up the console and see whether everything is going as it should be.

Comment: Strange, it seems it removes 20px from each element, maybe I should increase by 20px for each row of 3 elements. So that it would be -20px for the second row, -40px for the third and so on.

Comment: It seems I have to do as mentioned above, though not sure how do increase i++ only every third cycle.

Comment: Use `if (i % 3 == 0) i++`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `+=` syntax that animate also supports

```js
 $('.box1').css('top','+=20px');
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px; height:100px; position: absolute; top: 10px;
}

.box1 { background-color: red; left:10px; }
.box2 { background-color: yellow; left: 120px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```